# Error after new extension install

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-extensions

I have made a clean typo3 6.2.4 install and then installed the "news" extension. But if I now click on the extension in the left menu of the typo3 backend I get the following error:

> Table 'lanto01_typo3.tx_news_domain_model_category' doesn't exist.

I understand that the table is missing in the database. But how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Install Tool -> Important Actions and click on `Database Compare`. This compares your current database to the configuration files and you can automatically fix missing tables or fields.

In older TYPO3 versions (< 6.2) you'll find this in menu item Database Analyser in the Install Tool.

Comment: If the answer worked to solve your problem, please mark it as "correct answer".